# Copying only JPG from a directory structure to another location Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I wish to recursively go through the folders of a directory structure and copy any .jpg I find into another directory.

I think I had the wrong idea with:

```
cp -R photos/*.jpg /cpjpg
```

How can I do this from the command line in Ubuntu?

Comment: You'll get a better response on http://superuser.com. But you don't have to do anything - if enough people agree the question will be moved automatically.

Comment: Do you want them all to end up in one directory (flatten) or do you want to preserve the stucture?

Answer (score 13):

This will copy all files ending in .jpg or .jpeg (case insensitive as well) in the current directory and all its subdirectories to the directory /cpjpg.  The directory structure is not copied.

```
find . -type f \( -iname "*.jpg" -o -iname "*.jpeg" \) -exec cp '{}' /cpjpg \;
```

Answer (score 10):

This preserves the directory structure:

```
rsync -av --include='*.jpg' --include='*/' --exclude='*' SRC DST
```

see http://logbuffer.wordpress.com/2011/03/24/linux-copy-only-certain-filetypes-with-rsync-from-foldertree/

Answer (score 5):

This will preserve the directory structure.

```
find photos/ -type f \( -iname '*.jpg' -o -iname '*.jpeg' \) -print0 |xargs -0 tar c |(cd /cpjpg ; tar x)
```